# CSS - Help styling my menu items

Tags: asp.net, html, css

**CODE**

```
<div class="navheader">
     <ul class="navuseraccess">
        <li><a runat="server" id="mnuAccount" href="AccountSettings.aspx">My Account</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.navheader {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 775px;
    height: 43px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 20px 0px 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-image: url(../images/header_bkg_navmain.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

ul.navuseraccess {
    float: right;
    height: 43px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.navuseraccess li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 43px;
}
.navuseraccess li a {
    display: block;
    height: 43px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 43px;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is add a new listitem-anchor but want it to display beneath the existing one, and not next to it. So I'm guessing I'm going to have to move the existing one up a bit, then add a new one beneath it.

Comment: why does this have 2 votes for off-topic? it's vague, but definetely not off topic.

Comment: @RPM1984: Probably because the FAQ says, "Web design and HTML/CSS layout, and your job title is "designer", ask on Doctype." http://stackoverflow.com/faq (I didn't downvote, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `float` the elements. They are already *shrink-wrapped* because they are contained within a `position: absolute` element. This element will grow as needed, anchored to the bottom right of the page so long as you remove the `height` and `width` properties.

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/MJrfX/